# How to null a function in a process

Tags: c++, function, pointers, assembly, process

I have the function pointer to an address.

```
#define CSpellBookWnd__MemorizeSet                                 0x557CD8

    #define FUNCTION_AT_ADDRESS(function,offset) __declspec(naked) function\
{\
    __asm{mov eax, offset};\
    __asm{jmp eax};\
}

FUNCTION_AT_ADDRESS(void  CSpellBookWnd::MemorizeSet(int *,int),CSpellBookWnd__MemorizeSet);
```

I just want to instead of calling that function do some NOP's

Comment: I don't quite follow. Can you provide an example of intended usage? Do you mean "modify `FUNCTION_AT_ADDRESS` so that it's a NOP?" Or only some of the time?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to overwrite a function, you can't do this normally, as the memory pages are protected. How to set protection flags on a memory page is OS dependent. No assembler is needed for that though.

Answer (score 0):

That code looks like it's just creating a forwarding method that redirects to an implementation defined elsewhere. If you want the method to do nothing instead, just remove the `FUNCTION_AT_ADDRESS` call, and define your own empty method:

```
void  CSpellBookWnd::MemorizeSet(int *,int) {}
```